# Find the largest, smallest, sum and average of an array that stops at 0 in C

Tags: c, arrays

So basically I have to find the largest, smallest, sum, average of the zero terminated array.

I've gotten the average and sum to work but not find the largest smallest, the average of the positive and the negative numbers. The array stops when `0` is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c = 0, n, array[100], large, small;
    float sum = 0;
    //for (c = 0; c < n; n++) {
    do {
        c++;
        printf("\nEnter number:");
        scanf("%d", &array[c]);
        sum += array[c];
    } while (array[c] != 0);

    if (array[c] > large) { large = array[c]; }
    if (array[c] < small) { small = array[c]; }
    if (array[c] == 0) {
        printf("\n Sum = %.2f\n", sum);
        printf("\n Average = %.2f", sum / (c - 1));
        printf("\n Largest %d", large);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need the `if`s inside the `do { /* ... */ } while ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- array indexes start at `0` in C, you should not increment `c` until after you store the value.
- you do not actually need to store a value, just counting them it enough
- you should initialize `large` and `small` from the first value read.
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid input and avoid undefined behavior

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, n, large, small;
    double sum = 0;
    for (c = 0;; c++) {
        printf("Enter number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n == 0)
            break;
        sum += n;
        if (c == 0 || n > large) {
            large = n;
        }
        if (c == 0 || n < small) {
            small = n;
        }
    }
    if (c == 0) {
        printf("no numbers\n");
    } else {
        printf("Smallest: %d\n", small);
        printf("Largest: %d\n", large);
        printf("Sum = %f\n", sum);
        printf("Average = %.2f\n", sum / c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To illustrate how the above code works without a local array, here is an intermediary version with an array and come comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, n, i, array[100], large, small;
    double sum;
    for (c = 0; c < 100; c++) {     // loop reading into array, stop at array size
        printf("Enter number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)   // read a number, stop on failure
            break;
        if (n == 0)                 // stop when reading a 0
            break;
        array[c] = n;
    }
    if (c == 0) {
        printf("no numbers\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // initialize variables from first entry
    sum = array[0];
    large = small = array[0];
    // loop over remaining entries and update variables
    for (i = 1; i < c; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
        if (large < array[i]) {
            large = array[i];
        }
        if (small > array[i]) {
            small = array[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Smallest: %d\n", small);
    printf("Largest: %d\n", large);
    printf("Sum = %f\n", sum);
    printf("Average = %.2f\n", sum / c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so i can keep the middle part of  for (c = 0;; c++) { empy ?

Comment: Yes. this `for` loop iterates until `scanf()` return `!= 1` or reads a zero. `break;` exits the loop.

Comment: thanks, have trouble understanding how  for (c = 0;; c++) {
        printf("Enter number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n == 0)  records the numbers as n but c gives the values of larger and smaller

Comment: @Franco: I added a simpler version with an array.